# Running mvc 4 via iisexpress command line

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-express

Following are the standard steps we follow to run a MVC 4 site thru iisexpress in cmd line.

1. Register the site via Visual Studio
2. Then execute the following cmd "iisexpress /site:[SiteName]"

Our situation is we have multiple versions of the same MVC 4 site. If I have to switch between  different versions. Every time I have open VS and register the site then run it from cmdline. There should be easier way i.e. run without registering.

```
    I found we can use the following cmd line 

    iisexpress /path:[Site folder] /port:[portnumber]

    But accessing the site via browser I get HTTP 500 response.

    Am I missing something.
```